# Multi-input/Multi-output : Wrong output dimension when using KerasClassifier and GridSearchCV

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, dimensions, grid-search

**I have built a multi-input (100 features) multi-ouput (100 predictions) ANN model using keras and tensorflow.** I have been able to train my model and reach a quite satisfying accuracy on the test set using the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K 
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

def my_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred) : 
   d = K.sum(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1)
   n = K.sum((K.tanh(100000*y_true*y_pred)/2 + 0.5)*K.abs(y_true), axis = -1)
   return 1 - n/d

def my_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred) : 
   d = K.sum(K.abs(y_true))
   n = K.sum((K.tanh(100000*y_true*y_pred)/2 + 0.5)*K.abs(y_true))
   return n/d

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred) : 
   #print(y_true.shape, y_true)
   #print(y_pred.shape, y_true)
   acc = np.zeros([1, len(y_true)])
   for day in range(len(y_pred)) :
       d = 0
       n = 0
       for i in range(len(y_pred[0])) :
           d = d + abs(y_true[day, i])
           if np.sign(y_pred[day, i])*np.sign(y_true[day, i]) > 0 : 
               n = n + abs(y_true[day, i])
           else : 
               n = n + 0
       acc[0, day] = n/d
   return np.mean(acc, axis = -1)[0]

#Model
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, input_shape = (100, ), activation = "tanh"))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(units=100, activation = 'tanh'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = my_loss_fn, metrics = ['accuracy', my_metric_fn]) 

#Training
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', min_delta = 0.0001, patience = 20, verbose = 0, mode = 'min')
nb_epochs = 250
history = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = nb_epochs, batch_size = 31, callbacks = [callback], verbose = True, validation_split = 0., validation_data = (X_test, y_test), use_multiprocessing = True)

#Prediction
y_pred_train = classifier.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = classifier.predict(X_test)
acc_test = accuracy(y_test, y_pred_test)
acc_train = accuracy(y_train, y_pred_train)
```

I am trying to improve the performance of my model by tuning the hyperparameters so I used `KerasClassifier()` and `GridSearchCV()`. The following code illustrates my approach for the gridsearch.

```
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from tensorflow import autograph

#Building a function to create the classifier
def build_classifier(nb_layers, nb_nodes, optimizer, dropout, activation_fn):
    classifier=Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(units = nb_nodes, input_shape = (100, ), activation = activation_fn))
    for i in range(nb_layers-1) : 
        classifier.add(Dense(units = nb_nodes, activation = activation_fn, kernel_initializer = "uniform"))
        classifier.add(Dropout(dropout))
    classifier.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'tanh'))
    classifier.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert(my_loss_fn), metrics= ['accuracy', tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert(my_metric_fn)])
    return classifier

#Creating a scorer to feed to the GridSearchCV()
my_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy, greater_is_better = True)
classifier=KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_classifier)
parameters={'batch_size':[13, 31],'epochs':[100, 150], 'optimizer':['adam', 'rmsprop'], 'dropout' : [0.2, 0.1], 'nb_layers' : [2, 3], 'nb_nodes' : [45, 50, 110, 115], 'activation_fn' : ['relu', 'tanh']} 
grid_search=GridSearchCV(estimator=classifier, scoring = my_scorer, param_grid=parameters, cv=5, verbose = 1) 
grid_search=grid_search.fit(X_train_, y_train_raw)
```

When I fit my `GridSearchCV()` object I get the following error at the end of the first combination of hyperparameters (when the scoring is computed) :

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

I investigated by adding print commandes inside my `accuracy()` function

```
#print(y_true.shape, y_true)
#print(y_pred.shape, y_pred)
```

to print both the shape and the array `y_true` and `y_pred` given as inputs for my `accuracy()` function used as the `scoring` in the `GridSearchCV()` object.

I found out that `y_true.shape == (555, 100)` but `y_pred.shape == (555,)`. The value `555` corresponds to the number of lines of the fifth validation set because `cv = 5`.

**However, I do not understand why the prediction of the `gridsearch` is not a multi-output prediction even though the number of nodes of the last layer of the classifier is `(100,)`.**

Answer (score 0):

This was a regression problem so I used `KerasRegressor()` instead and it solved the issue. I guess that for a multi-output classification problem, `KerasClassifier()` expect the output to be a 2D hot encoded array.